# Turning Off the apache status error

Tags: php, apache, status, error-code

When I browse my site and the code reports a 500 error code, the browser shows me the message:

> > Unauthorized
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have to turn off this, becouse I send data extra in the body response.
Where is it in apache?

Thanks

Comment: Question is why that status is sent, although you say that it is you yourself who sends the reply (this is how I understand your last sentence). I mean usually one would solve the issue that actually occurs, so that leads to the error. Such an error should _never_ occur on a production site, regardless of whether it is caught and handled or not. It is a clear sign that there is some issue with the software that should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default error messages in Apache, use the [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) directive. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /internal/address.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://external.address/
ErrorDocument 500 "Custom error message"
```

This should work in an `.htaccess` file as well.